# gradle jacocoTestReport task is failing

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build.gradle, jacoco

> gradle jacocoTestReport --info

The following error is causing jenkins build failure.

```
   > Task :jacocoTestReport FAILED
    Caching disabled for task ':jacocoTestReport' because:
      Build cache is disabled
    Task ':jacocoTestReport' is not up-to-date because:
      Task has failed previously.
    [ant:jacocoReport] Loading execution data file C:\Users\*\build\jacoco\test.exec
    :jacocoTestReport (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.702 secs.

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':jacocoTestReport'.
    > Error while creating report
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_enable): You'll have to add `org.gradle.caching=true` into file `gradle.properties`.
And then build the whole project again, so that the previous task's output would have been cached.

Comment: No Help, Still getting the same issue

Comment: The weird thing is I have one if condition, if I comment that one then everything is working, otherwise jacocoTestReport is failing

Comment: @RavatTailor There is no `if` condition in the question; just fix that and it should always work.

Comment: gradle test generating jacoco direcotory in build, If I delete that and run jacocoTestReport then it is working fine

Comment: You could add a `Delete` task and make `jacocoTestReport` depend on it... this might be some kind of a workaround, but if it doesn't work otherwise, probably the most easy way, unless you could get rid the that one `if` condition, which might be the source of the problem. The question only features the error message, but not the code which produces it - therefore this is barely reproducible.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, Delete task work for me, but still not the perfect solution